# Как получить массив значений конкретного столбца из таблицы MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую. Есть таблица MySQL со столбцами `id` и `name`, например. Каким самым коротким путём я могу получить массив всех значений из столбца `name`?

Я, конечно, могу пройтись циклом и при помощи `mysqli_fetch_assoc` заносить значение из определенного столбца из каждого ряда в массив, но есть ли решения изящнее?

Comment: Ну или mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а потом выбирать массивы по столбцам через `array_column`, верно? Спасибо, ваш совет помог, оформите ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пишите SQL запрос, пример `SELECT id, name FROM tablename;`
2. Выполняете его и получаете результирующий набор `$result = $mysqli->query($query)`
3. Теперь из результирующего набора требуется извлечь данные `$array_data = $result->fetch_all()`. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Для PDO: PDOStatement::fetchAll сразу формирует массив из всех строк результирующего набора sql-запроса http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php

4. В итоге получаете массив `$array_data` из пар-значений id и name. Проверьте его var_damp'ом.